# select table from PHP MyAdmin using PHP file

Tags: php, mysql

Good day,
I am trying to select a table from MySQL and generaly I use this code:

```
$sql="CALL selectCreatedTableByName('".$tableNameIn."')";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
echo "<table id='restable'>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['nameE'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['nameN'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}

$conn->close();
```

but now, when I don't know the names of the table's columns, how can I select this table?

Thank you so much.

Comment: phpmyadmin is a in pfp written ide for mysql, so you really can't select a table from it, oly from your rdms which is MySQL

Comment: Run your stored procedure in phpmyadmin and see what the result is, but how can you have  stored procedure and don't know what is does?

Comment: because tables are going to be created by customers dynamically and i know only name from this table, so i must write code which will select this table knowing only name

Comment: So customers will first create a table with variable column names, and then at a later stage, you will need to access the data stored in each column?

Comment: yes, so now they can create tables with a lot of different columns and that works, so i only need to show this table data on my page. Of course i have access to DB and i can see which columns it is but of course i don't want to check it every day and create a special PHP file for each table

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, create two tables in your database. The first should have a table identification and the chosen names of the columns created by the customer. The second table should have the same table identification and also hold the data stored in each column. You can then match column titles to the data across the two tables in your database. Let me know if I have misunderstood you.

Comment: ok, but what should i put here in PHP code? echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['nameE'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['nameN'] . "</td>"; because here PHP call each column from table and i don't know them names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not selecting the table, you are selecting from the table. (at least I'm guessing that is the case since we don't know what your procedure actually does).

The PHP array returned uses the attribute names from the resultset as keys hence....

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr>\n";
    foreach($row as $name=>$value) {
        echo "<td>$value</td>\n";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

If you want a header row, then use a state variable to flag the first row.

```
$fetched=0;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if (!fetched) {
        echo "<tr>\n";
        foreach($row as $name=>$value) {
            echo "<th>$name</th>\n";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
    $fetched++;
    echo "<tr>\n";
    foreach($row as $name=>$value) {
        echo "<td>$value</td>\n";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
```